# Correct form of PHPDoc @return for hinting of arrays

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

As example, I have the following function

```
/**
 * Get the latest comment for a task
 * 
 * @param int $task_id
 * @return string[] Array of the form ['comment' => '', 'commenter' => '']
 */
function getLatestComment($task_id){

    // Default empty comment
    $latest_comment = ['comment' => '', 'commenter' => ''];

    // Go to database and select comment based on $task_id
    ...

    // If there is a comment, massage as required; assign to $latest_comment
    if ($comment_from_db){
       ...
    }

    return $latest_comment;
}
```

I'm using PhpStorm v2017.2.1

I'd like to document this function using PHPDoc such that making the following call, gives me intellisense/hint as to the nature of the returned value ($comment, in my code example below)

```
$comment = getLatestComment(1);
```

What is the correct form of the @return in my comment block?

**UPDATE**
I have received a request for clarification of my question. I'm trying to get the correct syntax such that my IDE not only hints the function's required params, but also the return type, inclusive of the properties (or string keys as is the case in PHP).

I have also added a screenshot which I hope helps.

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly do you wish to have in the end? Right now I see nothing wrong with your existing declaration and PHPDoc comment (although I personally would us just `array` instead of `string[]` as you have named array elements -- but that's just personal and does not change anything).

Comment: @LazyOne I have added clarification. Thnx

Comment: Neither PhpStorm or PHPDoc itself allows to type hint return array structure (you may typehint array structure for parameters `@param` but that does not work for `@return`). Use objects (custom classes) if you require proper typehints here.

Comment: If you just need to see what array keys are available -- you may see it already -- you need to invoke `View | Quick Documentation` on function. The drawback -- no help when typing key names + needs to be invoked on function call so cannot help if only variable is available here.